How to build dynamic table structure in SSRS
I am new to SSRS. I want to create a report in SSRS. My frontend is in react and backend uses .net and SQL Server. Somewhere I read that SSRS does not support dynamic table structure. is this true? or is there any way to achieve this? or any simplest alternative for this? any help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance
I tried in SSRS but could not find a way for this. I also tried to save HTML code via suneditor ( used in my react app ) in database and later getting that cade from database by API and tried to convert it in HTML, but no luck. Please help me in this.
